# Difference between returning new Promise and Promise.resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

For the below code snippet, i would like to understand how NodeJS runtime handles things :

```
const billion = 1000000000;

function longRunningTask(){
    let i = 0;
    while (i <= billion) i++;

    console.log(`Billion loops done.`);
}

function longRunningTaskProm(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let i = 0;
        while (i <= billion) i++;

        resolve(`Billion loops done : with promise.`);
    });
}

function longRunningTaskPromResolve(){
    return Promise.resolve().then(v => {
        let i = 0;
        while (i <= billion) i++;

        return `Billion loops done : with promise.resolve`;
    })
}


console.log(`*** STARTING ***`);

console.log(`1> Long Running Task`);
longRunningTask();

console.log(`2> Long Running Task that returns promise`);
longRunningTaskProm().then(console.log);

console.log(`3> Long Running Task that returns promise.resolve`);
longRunningTaskPromResolve().then(console.log);

console.log(`*** COMPLETED ***`);
```

1st approach :

> **longRunningTask()** function will block the main thread, as expected.

2nd approach :

> In **longRunningTaskProm()** wrapping the same code in a Promise, was expecting execution will move away from main thread and run as a micro-task. Doesn't seem so, would like to understand what's happening behind the scenes.

3rd approach :

> Third approach **longRunningTaskPromResolve()** works.

Here's my understanding :

> Creation and execution of a Promise is still hooked to the main thread. Only Promise resolved execution is moved as a micro-task.

Am kinda not convinced with whatever resources i found & with my understanding.

Comment: Be aware that Node.js executes your code in a single thread even promises. What I found interesting when I was reading about it was this article => https://blog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa

I hope it would help

Comment: Microtasks may run asynchronously, but that does not mean that they "*will move away from main thread*". It's just scheduled in a queue - all execution in one environment is single-threaded.

Comment: And yes, the `new Promise` callback *is* the promise creation. There is no "execution" of a promise, a promise is nothing that "runs" or is "executable".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three of these options run the code in the main thread and block the event loop.  There is a slight difference in timing for WHEN they start running the `while` loop code and when they block the event loop which will lead to a difference in when they run versus some of your console messages.

The first and second options block the event loop immediately.

The third option blocks the event loop starting on the next tick - that's when `Promise.resolve().then()` calls the callback you pass to `.then()` (on the next tick).

---

The first option is just pure synchronous code.  No surprise that it immediately blocks the event loop until the `while` loop is done.

In the second option the new Promise executor callback function is also called synchronously so again it blocks the event loop immediately until the `while` loop is done.

In the third option, it calls:

```
Promise.resolve().then(yourCallback);
```

The `Promise.resolve()` creates an already resolved promise and then calls `.then(yourCallback)` on that new promise.  This schedules `yourCallback` to run on the next tick of the event loop.  Per the promise specification, `.then()` handlers are always run on a future tick of the event loop, even if the promise is already resolved.

Meanwhile, any other Javascript right after this continues to run and only when that Javascript is done does the interpreter get to the next tick of the event loop and run `yourCallback`.  But, when it does run that callback, it's run in the main thread and therefore blocks until it's done.

> Creation and execution of a Promise is still hooked to the main thread. Only Promise resolved execution is moved as a micro-task.

All your code in your example is run in the main thread.  A `.then()` handler is scheduled to run in a future tick of the event loop (still in the main thread).  This scheduling uses a micro task queue which allows it to get in front of some other things in the event queue, but it still runs in the main thread and it still runs on a future tick of the event loop.

Also, the phrase "execution of a promise" is a bit of a misnomer.  Promises are a notification system and you schedule to run callbacks with them at some point in the future using `.then()` or `.catch()` or `.finally()` on a promise.  So, in general, you don't want to think of "executing a promise".   Your code executes causing a promise to get created and then you register callbacks on that promise to run in the future based on what happens with that promise.  Promises are a specialized event notification system.

---

Promises help notify you when things complete or help you schedule when things run.  They don't move tasks to another thread.

---

As an illustration, you can insert a `setTimeout(fn, 1)` right after the third option and see that the timeout is blocked from running until the third option finishes.  Here's an example of that.  And, I've made the blocking loops all be 1000ms long so you can more easily see.  Run this in the browser here or copy into a node.js file and run it there to see how the `setTimeout()` is blocked from executing on time by the execution time of `longRunningTaskPromResolve()`.  So, `longRunningTaskPromResolve()` is still blocking.  Putting it inside a `.then()` handler changes when it gets to run, but it is still blocking.

```js
const loopTime = 1000;

let startTime;
function log(...args) {
    if (!startTime) {
        startTime = Date.now();
    }
    let delta = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000;
    args.unshift(delta.toFixed(3) + ":");
    console.log(...args);
}

function longRunningTask(){
    log('longRunningTask() starting');
    let start = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() - start < loopTime) {}

    log('** longRunningTask() done **');
}

function longRunningTaskProm(){
    log('longRunningTaskProm() starting');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let start = Date.now();
        while (Date.now() - start < loopTime) {}
        log('About to call resolve() in longRunningTaskProm()');
        resolve('** longRunningTaskProm().then(handler) called **');
    });
}

function longRunningTaskPromResolve(){
    log('longRunningTaskPromResolve() starting');
    return Promise.resolve().then(v => {
        log('Start running .then() handler in longRunningTaskPromResolve()');
        let start = Date.now();
        while (Date.now() - start < loopTime) {}
        log('About to return from .then() in longRunningTaskPromResolve()');
        return '** longRunningTaskPromResolve().then(handler) called **';
    })
}


log('*** STARTING ***');

longRunningTask();

longRunningTaskProm().then(log);

longRunningTaskPromResolve().then(log);

log('Scheduling 1ms setTimeout')
setTimeout(() => {
    log('1ms setTimeout Got to Run');
}, 1);

log('*** First sequence of code completed, returning to event loop ***');
```

If you run this snippet and look at exactly when each message is output and the timing associated with each message, you can see the exact sequence of when things get to run.

Here's the output when I run it in node.js (line numbers added to help with the explanation below):

```
1    0.000: *** STARTING ***
2    0.005: longRunningTask() starting
3    1.006: ** longRunningTask() done **
4    1.006: longRunningTaskProm() starting
5    2.007: About to call resolve() in longRunningTaskProm()
6    2.007: longRunningTaskPromResolve() starting
7    2.008: Scheduling 1ms setTimeout
8    2.009: *** First sequence of code completed, returning to event loop ***
9    2.010: ** longRunningTaskProm().then(handler) called **
10   2.010: Start running .then() handler in longRunningTaskPromResolve()
11   3.010: About to return from .then() in longRunningTaskPromResolve()
12   3.010: ** longRunningTaskPromResolve().then(handler) called **
13   3.012: 1ms setTimeout Got to Run
```

Here's a step-by-step annotation:

1. Things start.
2. `longRunningTask()` initiated.
3. `longRunningTask()` completes.  It is entirely synchronous.
4. `longRunningTaskProm()` initiated.
5. `longRunningTaskProm()` calls `resolve()`.  You can see from this that the promise executor function (the callback passed to new Promise(fn)` is entirely synchronous too.
6. `longRunningTaskPromResolve()` initiated.  You can see that the handler from `longRunningTaskProm().then(handler)` has not yet been called.  That has been scheduled to run on the next tick of the event loop, but since we haven't gotten back to the event loop yet, it hasn't yet been called.
7. We're now setting the 1ms timer.  Note that this timer is being set only 1ms after we started `longRunningTaskPromResolve()`.  That's because `longRunningTaskPromResolve()` didn't do much yet.  It ran `Promise.resolve().then(handler)`, but all that did was schedule the `handler` to run on a future tick of the event loop.  So, that only took 1ms to schedule that.  The long running part of that function hasn't started running yet.
8. We get to the end of this sequence of code and return back to the event loop.
9. The next thing scheduled to run in the event loop is the handler from `longRunningTaskProm().then(handler)` so that gets called.  You can see that it was already waiting to run since it ran only 1ms after we returned to the event loop.  That handler runs and we return back to the event loop.
10. The next thing scheduled to run in the event loop is the handler from `Promise.resolve().then(handler)` so we now see that that starts to run and since it was already queued, it runs immediately after the previous event finished.
11. It takes exactly 1000ms for the loop in `longRunningTaskPromResolve()` to run and then it returns from it's `.then()` handler which schedules then next `.then()` handler in that promise chain to run on the next tick of the eventl loop.
12. That `.then()` gets to run.
13. Then, finally when there are no `.then()` handlers scheduled to run, the `setTimeout()` callback gets to run.  It was set to run in 1ms, but it got delayed by all the promise action running at a higher priority ahead of it so instead of running 1ms, it ran in 1004ms.

Comment: @BeingSuman - Added a runnable code snippet that shows how future code (such as a `setTimeout()`) is blocked by the execution of `longRunningTaskPromResolve()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jfriend00 for detailed explanation. To simplify, only Promise & executor function will run in first iteration directly on main thread. Resolved callbacks will resume the execution on main thread via event loop.

Comment: Follow up question, traditionally we write code like this : `async getUser(){return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { let data = await http.get(GET_API_URL); resolve(data);})}` This is similar to our 2nd case, does it mean executor function with API call will hang to main thread till we get data from API ?

Comment: @BeingSuman - That is not a traditional way to write code.  In fact, it's a wrong way to write code.  I can't tell what you're really asking with the executor function, but you should not be using await inside the executor function.  `await` never hangs the main thread in JS.  It just pauses that function itself and all other events can still run.  If you want to illustrate/describe an example better, perhaps you should write a new question and show the full problem.

Comment: here's the [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671321/)

Comment: Might be worth explaining what you call "next tick" here. Reading your answer it sounds like it would be next iteration of the event loop. It isn't. Node made an unfortunate choice of naming `process.nextTick` this way, but the execution of microtasks (and `nextTick()` callbacks in node) are made **before** the next event loop. This means if you have a recursive `const foo = () => Promise.resolve().then(foo);` calling `foo()` will actually block the event loop in a `while(true)` like synchronous way.

Comment: @Kaiido - Yeah, there are essentially multiple priorities of ticks and the highest priority ones can dominate if they are running repeatedly.  I'm not sure I really wanted to go into all that here as it could really lose some people.  "tick" here just meant a future cycle of the event loop after this one is done without any desire to match it to `process.nextTick()` which is a more specific type of tick.

Comment: Well that's the thing, micro-tasks have no priority, they are just executed synchronously after the task that did queue them got executed. Yes tasks have priorities, but micro-tasks are even an other beast. So no, it's not "a future cycle of the event loop after this one is done", it's really the same cycle.

Comment: @Kaiido - You're making a semantic argument here.  The stack fully unwinds before they are processed and other promise waiting to run their `.then()` handlers may go first (further complicating things).   I don't think your semantic argument is germaine to the point of this answer and to try to explain all that here would make the answer 2-3 times as long (it's already pretty long) and probably lose 3/4 of the audience.  If you have a specific recommendation for a few words to change that make things clearer in this regard and don't confuse people, I'll entertain that.

Comment: Well simply stating *after the current task gets executed*, is both short, correct and I guess quite graspable for any audience with a minimal knowledge in the field. It's not just semantic, node's event loop is still quite simple, but if you take the HTML's event loop, there are so many things that should happen in a single iteration that will get blocked by these synchronous  micro-tasks checkpoint that it's a really important distinction. It's too often we see people expect the UI to not freeze because they did `doSynchronous1().then( doSynchronous2 ).then( doSynchronous3 )...`

Comment: @Kaiido - I went to try to make that substitution replacing "on the next tick", with "after the current task gets executed", but it appears that nobody will know what "after the current task gets executed" really means since there's no background here at all that describes what that is (there's no discussion in here of what a "task" is.  I'll think about it some more.